# How to create the 30 days trial setup with wix?

Tags: wix, trial

I am trying to create the installer for my product.It must be work for 30 days after installation.After 30 days it must expire and make the application not to work.Please tell me how can i do this in wix ?

Comment: Wix is just for installing your application. You have to check **within your application** if the trial period has expired. WiX can just aid you in e.g. writing the installation date into the registry, install a period checker in the autostart etc.

Comment: How can I control the trial installer to install in a system only once(30 days) , even changing the date manually ?

Comment: As said, the installer can just help you with the needed registry entries etc. Check the following links on how you can create a trial application. Depending on the mechanism used, you can then add the related entries in the installer (if any are needed at all):

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this in the main application executable. More flexible and reliable. You can also do it in a custom action that tags a part of the registry in a fashion to indicate install and expiration date.

Personally I think it is safer to have the application contact a server, get today's date and then set up the application to stop working in 30 days, and if you can't contact a server default to the system's time and date, and verify that it was correct when network connection is available.

Comment: I agree, this the best approach.